# Throwing Nan message for a property of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, observable

I have developed an Angular4 appln that calls a nodeExpressJS server to fetch JSON data and also adds data to the JSON object. The following is the onSubmit function of the addemployeeform.

```
onSubmit(formValue: any) {
    console.log("Form Value = " + JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 4));
    let newEmployee: Emp;
    let last: any;
    this._employeeService.lastEmployeeID().subscribe((last: any) => last = last,
        err => console.log(err));
    newEmployee = {
        //id: employeeCount + 1,
        id: last + 1,
        name: formValue.name,
        manufacturer: formValue.manufacturer,
        type: formValue.type,
        batchno: formValue.batchno,
        expdate: formValue.expdate,
        price: formValue.price
    };
    // console.log(newEmployee.id );
    let temp = this._employeeService.addEmployee(newEmployee).subscribe(err =>
        console.log(err));
    this.router.navigate(['employees']);
}
```

But then it isn't pushing the id property to the JSON for newEmployee.

```
{id: 1, name: "Paracetamol", manufacturer: "Ranbaxy", type: "Tablet", batchno …}

{id: 2, name: "Sinarest", manufacturer: "GSK", type: "Tablet", batchno: …}

{id: 3, name: "Viagra", manufacturer: "Pfizer", type: "Capsule", batchno: …} 

{name: "Aspirine", manufacturer: "Aspirine", type: "Syrup", batchno: "03/46", expdate: "03/04/2023", …}
```

`newEmployee` is Aspirine.

And on uncommenting `console.log(newEmployee.id );` line of code

I get a Nan error

Answer (score 1):

First, shouldn't `last` be defined as a `number` and not `any`?

Second, and more importantly, the lastEmployeeId call is most likely asynchronous, meaning it will not have completed before the next line of code is complete. You need to add all of the code that executes after that operation within the subscribe.

```
this._employeeService.lastEmployeeID().subscribe(
 (last: any) => {
    last = last;
    newEmployee = {
      //id: employeeCount + 1,
      id: last + 1,
      name: formValue.name,
      manufacturer: formValue.manufacturer,
      type: formValue.type,
      batchno: formValue.batchno,
      expdate: formValue.expdate,
      price: formValue.price
  };
  // console.log(newEmployee.id );
  let temp = this._employeeService.addEmployee(newEmployee).subscribe(
    employee => {
       console.log(employee);
       this.router.navigate(['employees']);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
```

And with that much code in the first function passed to your subscribe, you may want to instead make it it's own function:

```
this._employeeService.lastEmployeeID().subscribe(
   (last: number) => this.processEmployeeId(last),
    err => console.log(err));

processEmployeeId(last: number) {
   // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Added all of the code within the subscribe
Now getting an error 
that the id property can't be set.

Comment: Does the error provide any more information? It may be easier to post that as a new question so you can provided the updated code...

Comment: Also my lastEmployeeID is returning an observable , so should i keep my last as last:Observable<{}>

Comment: If you want to create a plunker or stackblitz with the minimum possible example of your issue, we can take a closer look.

Comment: this._employeeService.addEmployee(newEmployee).
    subscribe(()=>
     {
      
     this._employeeService.lastEmployeeID().
    subscribe((last:number)=> 

    {console.log(last+3),newEmployee.id=last+3,

      newEmployee.name= formValue.name

      newEmployee.manufacturer=formValue.manufacturer,

      newEmployee.type= formValue.type,

      newEmployee.batchno= formValue.batchno,

      newEmployee.expdate= formValue.expdate,

      newEmployee.price= formValue.price
      }
     ,err => console.log(err));

      },err => console.log(err));

Two async calls

Comment: It is really difficult to read code in comments due to the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

if `last` is supposed to be a number type then state so:

```
let last: number;
```

If you're going to use typescript - you might as well use it to your advantage.